# kubectl exec command not working from powershell ISE (works from powershell) - Is there a reason or workaround to make it work?

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, exec, kubectl, powershell-ise

I have recently started working with Kubernetes and Docker and still new with how it all works. I have made a ps1 script to run all the steps I need to do to build image and execute image on Kubernetes.

What I see is all steps work fine on ISE (except this one: "kubectl exec -it test-runner pwsh"). For this step alone, I have to run it on another PowerShell window.

When I run this step in ISE, the script keeps running without ever giving any error or stopping.

Does anyone know if its a limitation with Kubernetes working on ISE or if there is a workaround to make it work?

Working with ISE is quick and saves me tons of time, so this really makes a difference when I have to copy, paste, enter this each time in a separate PowerShell window.

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S: I looked at other suggested similar questions/answers and none of them seem to be related to Kubernetes not working on ISE. Hence this question.

command:

```
kubectl exec -it test-runner pwsh
```

Expected (and actual when running from PowerShell console):

```
----------------------
PS C:\windows\system32> kubectl exec -it test-runner pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /test>
-----------------------------
Actual (when running from PowerShell ISE):

PS C:\SourceCodeTLM\Apollo>  kubectl exec -it test-runner pwsh
PowerShell 6.2.2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

(with a blinking cursor and script running without breaking and changing to the new path)...
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The PowerShell *ISE* doesn't support *interactive* console applications**, which notably means that you cannot start other *shells* from it.

The ISE tries to anticipate that problem by refusing to start well-known shells.
For instance, trying to start `cmd.exe` fails with the following error message:

```
Cannot start "cmd". Interactive console applications are not supported. 
To run the application, use the Start-Process cmdlet or use 
"Start PowerShell.exe" from the File menu.
```

Note:

- `pwsh.exe`, the CLI of PowerShell (Core) 7+, is *not* among the well-known shells, which indicates the **[ISE's obsolescent status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)**. It is **being superseded by [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)**. Obsolesence aside, there are other pitfalls - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

However, it is impossible for the ISE to detect all cases where a given command (ultimately) invokes an interactive console application; when it doesn't, **invocation of the command is attempted, resulting in obscure error messages or, as in your case, hangs**.

As the error message shown for `cmd.exe` implies, **you must run interactive console applications *outside* the ISE, in a regular console window.**

**From the ISE** you can **use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) to launch a program in a new, regular console window**; in the case at hand:

```
Start-Process kubectl 'exec -it test-runner pwsh'
```

**Alternatively**, run your PowerShell sessions outside the ISE to begin with, such as in a regular console window, **Windows Terminal**, or in **Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal**.

Answer (score 0):

After digging out, I found a way to interact with the interactive console applications.

we can use `SendKeys('key_here')` to specific application.

Comment: Note that this question is about the _fundamental inability_ to run interactive console applications _in the ISE_. You're answering a different question, namely _how to automate interacting_ with an interactive console application (which is better done via the pipeline / stdin rather than via simulated user actions, the latter being invariably brittle).

Comment: oh ok i misunderstood it, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a command window from PowerShell and send the command to open the shell.

```
Start-Process PowerShell -Wait "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"kubectl exec helloworld-web-8495f4c888-jw2tg -n local-v1 -it -- /bin/bash`""
```